# computing the shortest distance of a maze with the boe-bot in Pbasic

Tags: algorithm, robotics, path-finding, basic

I'm working on a project with a robot called the boe-bot.

My goal is to traverse through a maze twice. On the first run, my boe-bot transverses through the maze storing the paths taken in memory. On the second run, it has all the paths stored in memory and deletes the bad paths that lead to dead ends -- so the boe-bot can take the shortest path to the end of the maze.

In order to do this, I need to create replacement rules to parse out bad routes that lead to dead ends.

I created a code in pbasic but my code gets errors. Is there anyone out there that can help me out with this?

```
' {$STAMP BS2}
' {$PBASIC 2.5}



' -----[ Variables ]----------------------------------------------------------
turn VAR Word
turns VAR Word
pointer VAR Byte
ptr VAR pointer 'create an alias for pointer

' -----[ Main Routine ]-------------------------------------------------------
DO ' Begin main routine

ptr = 0 'Points TO the NEXT available position in the array.

turns(ptr) = turn 'This puts an L in the first position of the array or left turn in array

ptr = ptr + 1  'Add one TO the pointer so the NEXT letter goes in the NEXT position in the array.

IF (turns < 3)THEN 'Array needs at least three characters for this algorithm to work
RETURN
IF (turns(3)(ptr) - 1 <> "U")THEN 'EXIT IF the NEXT-TO-last turn is NOT a U-Turn
RETURN

IF (turns(3) = "LUL") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Left U-Turn Left 
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "S" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "LUR") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Left U-Turn Right
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "U" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "LUS") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Left U-turn Straight
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "R" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.
' Increment/decrement routine only changes pulse durations by 2 at a time.

IF (turns(3) == "RUL") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Right U-turn Left 
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "U" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "RUR") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Right U-turn Right
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "L" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "RUS") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Right U-turn Straight
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "L" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer to point to the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "SUL") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Straight U-turn Left 
ptr = ptr - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(ptr) = "R" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
ptr = ptr + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "SUR") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Straight U-turn Right
pointer = pointer - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(pointer) = "L" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
pointer = pointer + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.

IF (turns(3) == "SUS") 'Look at the right three characters in the array Straight U-turn Straight 
pointer = pointer - 3 'shorten the array by 3 characters. We'll "chop off" the LUL and replace with S
turns(pointer) = "U" 'The turn we should have taken (AND will take NEXT time.
pointer = pointer + 1 'set up the pointer TO point TO the NEXT character in the array.
```

Comment: Is your problem with syntax, or with the algorithm?

Comment: If you want to get better answers, you may want to add more tags (pbasic, etc), the outputted errors, and (possibly) pseudocode. http://sscce.org/

Comment: you really need to post your errors.

Comment: Please checkout and contribute to the new robotics stackexchange forum: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics

Answer (score 1):

This maze solving method is a simple version of the A* planning algorithm.  You may want to checkout my page that describes this maze solving method: http://www.benaxelrod.com/robots/maze/index.html

There is pseudo code there that may help you fix your code.